# Can't access stsTokenManager from firebase response of createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using react native signup form that invokes `firbase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);`
I am using in code as follows in a trycatch:

```
const result = await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    console.log(result.user.stsTokenManager);
```

If i console log `result.user` i see an stsTokenManager object that has info about the provided token but if i try to console log `result.user.stsTokenManager` i get undefined.
Would be great if anyone knows the reason this is happening and why i cant access a specific object in the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the below request, the variable `credential` is a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object.

```
const credential = await firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

A `UserCredential` is made up of:

```js
{
  additionalUserInfo?: null | {
    isNewUser: boolean;
    profile: Object | null;
    providerId: string;
    username?: string | null
  };
  credential: AuthCredential | null;
  operationType?: string | null;
  user: User | null
}
```

*Documentation: [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) and [`AuthCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthCredential)*

As you can see from the documentation for [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User), the property `stsTokenManager` doesn't exist as it is an internal property.

**This means you shouldn't be using it.**

When you look at the source code of `fireauth.AuthUser`, the property is actually called `stsTokenManager_`, as defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/50195991a514d16ee40d08fe32d308111f7917e3/packages/auth/src/authuser.js#L194-195). It is accessed using `user.getStsTokenManager()`, as defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/50195991a514d16ee40d08fe32d308111f7917e3/packages/auth/src/authuser.js#L727-L730).

So then, why does the console log it as `stsTokenManager`? This is because the `fireauth.AuthUser.prototype.toJSON()` method is called, which calls the `fireauth.AuthUser.prototype.toPlainObject()` method where it is exported as `stsTokenManager`, as defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/50195991a514d16ee40d08fe32d308111f7917e3/packages/auth/src/authuser.js#L2366-L2409).

So you should be able to log the access token using either of the following:

```
console.log(result.user.getStsTokenManager().accessToken);

console.log(result.user.toPlainObject().stsTokenManager.accessToken);
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why stsTokenManager is evaluated on stringifying, and isn't available on accesing it by key name?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by transforming response to JSON

```
result.user.toJSON().stsTokenManager.accessToken
```

Answer (score 2):

Very straightforward I'd say, but this is how I resolved it regardless of whether firestore is not exposing it as a public property or method.

```
const result = await firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);


    console.log(result.user['stsTokenManager']);
```